# seven (7) boom game in one line code python

Tags: python

I need to create a game that every number that divides in 7 or has the digit 7 should be printed as boom:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 boom 8 ... 13 boom 15 16 boom ...]
```

my line get invalid text. I think its because of the mix of int and str. not shore what to do to fix the code.

```
boom7 = [x = "boom" if 7 in x else x*1 for x in range(1,99)]
print(boom7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

almost, this should do it

```
[ "boom" if "7" in str(x) or x%7==0 else x for x in range(1,99)]
```

let me know if you need explaining

Answer (score -2):

```
def seven_boom(end_number):
    for x in range(0,end_number+1):
        str_first = str(x)
        replace_first_num = str_first.replace(str_first[0],"boom")
        if "7" in str_first or x%7 ==0:
            new_seven_boom = str_first.replace(str_first,"boom")
            print(new_seven_boom)
        else:
            print(x)
        replace_last_num = str_first.replace(str_first[-1],"boom")
seven_boom(27)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This question is almost two years old and already has a very simple accepted answer. Why should we read and use your version instead?